# How to get some CAN address messages with ELM327

Tags: elm327

I'm trying to get some CAN messages with ELM327.

But I couldn't handle it.

Please let me know about ELM327's AT command.

For example, How can I get only 1AA and 2BB address messages?

I coudn't understand AT CF & CM command.

I tried below command but ELM327 recieved many other address data.
"AT CF 1AA"
"AT CF 2BB"
"AT MA"

Answer (score 0):

All of this is documented in the ELM327 AT command manual. You will need to figure out the bit mask and the filter of addresses you want to allow and set those with `ATCF` and `ATCM` respectively. For example:

```
Mask Value: 0b11111111110 (0x03FE)
Filter Value: 0b11111111111 (0x03FF)
The Rx buffer will receive CAN frames with an Id of 0x03FE or 0x03FF as bit 0 of the filter bit is disabled.
```

More examples can be found at https://www.microchip.com/forums/m318430.aspx.